# Pandas select closest date in past

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Being a beginner with `pandas`, I wonder how I can select the *closest* date in the past? E.g. I  have a `dataframe` as follows:

```
               Terminart                        Info     Datum  Ergebnis
0       Hauptversammlung                         NaN  22.06.16       NaN
1        Jahresabschluss                        2015  10.03.16       NaN
2         Quartalszahlen                     Q3 2015  28.10.15       NaN
3         Quartalszahlen                     Q2 2015  29.07.15       NaN
4       Hauptversammlung                         NaN  05.05.15       NaN
5         Quartalszahlen                     Q1 2015  29.04.15       NaN
6  Bilanzpressekonferenz                        2014  12.03.15       NaN
7  Bilanzpressekonferenz  Jahrespressekonferenz 2015  12.03.15       NaN
```

---

I can select the `Terminart` with `df.loc()`, ie:

```
df.loc[df['Terminart'] == 'Hauptversammlung']
```

selects only two rows (which is correct).

---

However, how can I select the *closest date* in the past? It would be the first row (`06/22/16`) here? The dataframe is not ordered by default.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can convert [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) column `Datum` and then first filter lower as no difference (timedelta=0) and then find index of max value by [`idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.idxmax.html):

*Notice : In sample is changed last datetime for better testing*

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

print (df)
                                     Terminart     Info     Datum  Ergebnis
0                             Hauptversammlung      NaN  22.06.16       NaN
1                              Jahresabschluss     2015  10.03.16       NaN
2                               Quartalszahlen  Q3 2015  28.10.15       NaN
3                               Quartalszahlen  Q2 2015  29.07.15       NaN
4                             Hauptversammlung      NaN  05.05.15       NaN
5                               Quartalszahlen  Q1 2015  29.04.15       NaN
6                        Bilanzpressekonferenz     2014  12.03.15       NaN
7  Bilanzpressekonferenz Jahrespressekonferenz     2015  19.07.16       NaN
```

```
df['Datum'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Datum, format='%d.%m.%y')

date = dt.datetime.now().date()
print (date)
2016-07-17

diff = (df.Datum - date)
print (diff)
0    -25 days
1   -129 days
2   -263 days
3   -354 days
4   -439 days
5   -445 days
6   -493 days
7      2 days
Name: Datum, dtype: timedelta64[ns]

indexmax = (diff[(diff < pd.to_timedelta(0))].idxmax())

print (df.ix[[indexmax]])
          Terminart Info      Datum  Ergebnis
0  Hauptversammlung  NaN 2016-06-22       NaN
```

Comment: Sorry, for the follow-up: implementing your code, how can I restrict the found dates to a value in `Terminart`, let's say I only want to look for dates with `'Teminart' == 'Quartalszahlen'` - can this be done?

Comment: even a couple of seconds

Comment: It is impossible select by index and use condition  so you can use `print (df[(df.Terminart == 'Quartalszahlen') & (df.index == indexmax)])`

Comment: Or another solution is `print (df[df.Terminart == 'Quartalszahlen'].ix[[indexmax]])
`

Answer (score 0):

First you convert your column 'Datum' to a date field with `to_datetime()` then you can just sort your dataframe by date with `sort_values()` and then print out the first row:

```
df['Datum'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Datum'], format='%d.%m.%y')
df.sort_values('Datum')
print(df.iloc[0])
```

Comment: While this works - sorting is going to be more expensive than just finding the max as shown in jezrael's answer...

Comment: And also there is problem you need find max date in `past`, so if there are datetimes in future, your solution failed.

Comment: I used @jezrael answer (cause of the past values), thanks for your effort though!

Comment: Ok I just assumed your data had only past data :)